# ASP.NET C# Edit SqlDataSource record without FormView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-update, sqldatasource

How can Edit SqlDataSource record without FormView?
I knows getting data into TextBox, But can't save changes.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   DataView dvSql = (DataView)EmployData.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
   foreach (DataRowView drvSql in dvSql)
   {
     E_ID.Text = drvSql["ID"].ToString();
     E_LName.Text = drvSql["LName"].ToString();
     ...
    }
}

protected void SaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EmployData.UpdateParameters.Add("ID", E_ID);
    EmployData.UpdateParameters.Add("LName", E_LName);
    ....

    EmployData.Update();        
 }
```

Thank's.

Comment: What's the error when you save changes?

Comment: No error. I think it save existing textbox text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So simple...

Add on Load_Page before read code:

```
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        { }
        else
        {

            DataView dvSql = (DataView)EmployData.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
....
....
}
```

Good Day.